# how to select a column range when importing data from flat file into sql, if the data in file didn't separated with any tags like comma and semicolon

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, flat-file

If data like

```
"700133 70013303102021SC  25 210604580000000440"
"700133 70013303102021SC  26 210604600000010000"
```

need roll number like "80000000440" and "600000010000"
how will separate the data and to load in table which are already  created

Comment: Simple searching will find many example and discussions of importing text files into a database using tools provided with SQL Server. If you don't have separators, then presumably your file contains data in a fixed format / position. That's an option with the wizard - suggest you give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't sufficient Information about DB and how you would load this data to any table. Because of this I could share only SELECT Query with you :

```
SQL SERVER:
SELECT RIGHT('700133 70013303102021SC  25 210604580000000440', 11) AS String;

ORACLE:
select substr('700133 70013303102021SC  25 210604580000000440',-11) AS String from dual;
```

Comment: the data is in flat file without separation, if we have separations we can proceed with SELECT and INSERT INTO and BULK INSERT also

Comment: You are right. Without delimiter/separator it is harder. If I could find a way to do it, I will share it with you.